# ElasticSearch: 1 index vs 2 indices

Tags: elasticsearch, ibeacon-android

I currently am developing a solution for a system that uses BLE technology on mobile phones, to post check-in/checkout data through beacons to a server. The server then sends the check-in/checkout data to an ElasticSearch instance, which is then queried at will. I currently have two indices: One for the check-in data, and another one for the checkout data. Both, my check-in and checkout data have three fields only: A `deviceUUID`, the `beaconId`, and the `timestamp` which is basically the time when a mobile user has entered the beacon range (check-in), or exited the range (checkout).

Now I can easily query my check-in and checkout data in isolation from each other. E.g: Counting the number of times a user has entered the range of a specific beacon between two specific dates.But, I'm not sure how I would be able to compute the period of time for which a user has spent within the beacon range on a given day for example, (Which is basically the difference between the check-in and the checkout time). So my questions are:

1- For this given system, is having a single index a better practice? Or was I right to have two separates indices?
2- Based on the answer of my first question, How can I get the period of time for which a user has spent within the beacon range?

Note: My data is posted as a JSON string from the mobile phones.

Answer (score 0):

When receiving check out, query last check in then save checkout in a separate type (table) with calculated spent time. It will make a lot easier to do analysis later.

Comment: But this means that with every checkout, I'd have to retrieve the last checkin, compute the difference, and then store the difference, making sure to also store the deviceUUID (Again), and the checkin/checkout times (Again). I'm on the verge of finding the right solution for this problem. I will post it once it's ready. Thanks a ton for the suggestion Tomas!